# The review icon shows red when there is nothing to review. Is it by-design?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, top-bar

I am sure I am not banned (Or Am I?) from reviewing queues. I have been observing this since many days that a red dot appears only when all review queues are cleared. And when there actually is anything to review, that red dot won't come. (See images 1 and 2)

Is this by-design or some reverse implementation of logic or may be it is red for other queues whose rep I haven't earned to access?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: You are not banned from reviewing. And there actually *are* things to review, they've just been handed out to reviewers since the time the dot showed up and the time you clicked on it. The dot is working *very* well at attracting the attention of prospective reviewers. Possibly too well. Shog9 has had to increase the "danger" threshold at least once already. It might be time to up it again.

Comment: @CodyGray Same issue on [su], but it seems like it might be for a queue I don't have access to, like say the close-vote queue. When I clicked "all queues" there was a grand total of 7 reviews waiting, in all queues. This is after a <1 minute latency from when I noticed the red icon. Are reviews *really* being handed out that quickly? https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMMUe.png